# Not receiving response from php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently i am trying to send email using PHPMailer after submitting registration form but i am successfully receiving the email but not getting redirected or getting any message notice box after email has been sent.

**The Signup form**

```html
        <form id="form_register" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <span id="log"></span>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="username" class="col-xs-12 mb0">Username</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="login-password" class="col-xs-12 mb0">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="login-password" class="col-xs-12 mb0">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="login-password" class="col-xs-12 mb0">Email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="login-password" class="col-xs-12 mb0">Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb5">
                <label for="login-password" class="col-xs-12 mb0">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_pass" id="confirm_pass">
                </div>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-left" for="gender">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" size="1">
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-sm btn-warning btn-block" name="create_account" id="create_account"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Here is the ajax work:**

```js
    function regform()
    {  
   var data = $("#form_register").serialize();
   $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'core/register.class.php',
   data : data,
   beforeSend: function()
   { 
    $("#log").fadeOut();
    $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
   },      
   success : function(response){
     if(response=="emptycaptcha"){
      $("#log").fadeIn();
      $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Empty Captcha</strong> Please fill in the captcha to continue.</div>');
      $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');   
     }else if(response=="wrongcaptcha"){ 
      $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Wrong Captcha</strong> Please fill in the captcha correctly.</div>');
      $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
     }else if((response=="noact") || (response=="adminact")){
      $("#log").fadeIn();
      $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-success"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Successfully Registered!</strong> You will be redirected to Login Page...</div>');
      $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
      setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = "login.php";
      }, 5000);     
     }else if(response=="emailact"){
      $("#log").fadeIn();
      $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-success"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Successfully Registered!</strong> A Verification Email has been sent to your email.You will be redirected to verification page...</div>');
      $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
      var uemail = $('#email').val();
      setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = "verification.php?verify="+uemail;
      }, 5000);    
     }  
   },    
    error: function(response){
     $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Error !</strong> Something went wrong.</div>');
    }
   });
    return false;
  }
```

**Here is the PHP part which receives my form inputs and send code and email to the email php file**

```
    if (isset($_POST['create_account'])){   
            $username = trim($_POST['username']);
             $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
             $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
             $email = trim($_POST['email']);
             $pass = trim($_POST['password']);
             $password = PASSWORD_HASH($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
             $gender = $_POST['gender'];
             $code = mt_rand(1111111, 9999999); 
             $reg_date = date('Y-m-d');
            try{
                $rai = $db_con->prepare("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
                $rai->execute();                        
                if($settings['account_act']=='noact'){
                    $v_status = 'true';
                    $a_status = 'true';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    echo 'noact';
                }else if($settings['account_act']=='emailact'){
                    $v_status = 'false';
                    $a_status = 'false';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    send_code($code,$email);
                    echo 'emailact';    
                    }
                }else if($settings['account_act']=='adminact'){
                    $v_status = 'false';
                    $a_status = 'false';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    echo 'adminact';
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "sorry".$e->getMessage();
            }
}
```

**The email.class.php**

```
function send_code($code,$email){
//Load composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxx';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxx');
    $mail->addAddress($email, 'User');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>'.$code;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    $mail->send();  
    //echo 'Message has been sent';
    header('location:../verification.php?verify='.$email);
    //echo 'emailact';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

}

Now if i remove the send_code($code,$email) from the register.class.php then i am successfully receiving the redirection and notice.I have tried almost 3 hours but not getting to any point.

**UPDATE1:**
i have enabled error_reporting and display_error but i am not receiving any errors in the phperror log and also no error in the console of chrome .
I have tried using console.log(response) and i am receiving the email in my gmail properly and also i am receiving the response 'emailact' properly but why am i not getting redirected? the log is as follow :

**2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>9759376

2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: 

2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: 

2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_vph8ZrSzb5duNdneV6Z64s04gZP7o2um2oEAjFQXso--

2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: 

2018-07-21 14:53:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: .

2018-07-21 14:53:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1532184784 v4-v6sm5199360wra.22 - gsmtp

2018-07-21 14:53:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2018-07-21 14:53:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection v4-v6sm5199360wra.22 - gsmtp

emailact**

**UPDATE 2:(SOLVED)**
At last i solved it its not the issue with the email.class.php but i think its with the response in my final log console.log(response) i was receiving the complete work load of php mailer well i think the whole log along with the 'emailact' that i was echoing ,was the 'response'.By considering this i arranged js in success function as follows:

```js
success : function(response){
 console.log(response);
  if(response=="emptycaptcha"){
   $("#log").fadeIn();
   $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Empty Captcha</strong> Please fill in the captcha to continue.</div>');
   $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');   
  }else if(response=="wrongcaptcha"){ 
   $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Wrong Captcha</strong> Please fill in the captcha correctly.</div>');
   $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
  }else if((response=="noact") || (response=="adminact")){
   $("#log").fadeIn();
   $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-success"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Successfully Registered!</strong> You will be redirected to Login Page...</div>');
   $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
   setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "login.php";
   }, 5000);     
  }else{
  //if(response == "emailact"){
   $("#log").fadeIn();
   $("#log").html('<div class="notice notice-sm notice-success"><strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Successfully Registered!</strong> A Verification Email has been sent to your email.You will be redirected to verification page...</div>');
   $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up');
   var uemail = $('#email').val();
   setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href= "verification.php?verify="+uemail;
   }, 5000);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `window.location.href` try `window.location` to preform the actual redirect

Comment: the window.location.href works also but i think there is an issue with the email.class.php that why the i am not recieving the response even though i am receiving the mail by the email.calss.php

Comment: remove header('location:../verification.php?verify='.$email);

Comment: still not receiving message or redirection.Does not seems to work.

Comment: did you check the response that you are receiving on the ajax side?

Comment: where are you calling the function regform()?

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and enable full error reporting, and look to your server logs if you are receiving a 500 error in your web browser network tab during the ajax call. Or look at the raw response data if you are not receiving a 500. You say you get a response if you do NOT call `send_code`... which means your issue lies squarely in your function definition of `send_code`. Add this `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` every time you create a new account. That is probably causing a mysql error by trying to create a duplicate `id` on every new account you create

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: thanks for the prepared statement guide (this is not my final version i will try to make prepared statements before finalizing this project).

Comment: please check my question update.

Comment: i see that the curly braces are not balance in email.class.php. if it is copying mistake then sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajax` is fine and it's sending data to the `php` file but, `php` cannot access the information because yo didn't define (I don't know what they call this) Let's say method name:

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'core/register.class.php',
            data : {'create_account': data}, //********this is too important!!!
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                $("#log").fadeOut();
                $("#create_account").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
            },
```

The second thing is in your `core/register.class.php` you didn't define the parameters correctly, This is the right way to get the serialized data:

```
if (isset($_POST['create_account'])){   
            $get = explode('&', $_POST['create_account'] ); // explode with &

            foreach ( $get as $key => $value) {
                $valn[ substr( $value, 0 , strpos( $value, '=' ) ) ] =  substr( $value,                strpos( $value, '=' ) + 1 ) ;
            }

        // access your query param
        $username = trim($valn['username']);
        $first_name = trim($valn['first_name']);
        $last_name = trim($valn['last_name']);
        $email = trim($valn['email']);
        $pass = trim($valn['password']);
        $password = PASSWORD_HASH($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $gender = $valn['gender'];
        $code = mt_rand(1111111, 9999999); 
        $reg_date = date('Y-m-d');
            try{
                $rai = $db_con->prepare("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
                $rai->execute();                        
                if($settings['account_act']=='noact'){
                    $v_status = 'true';
                    $a_status = 'true';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    echo 'noact';
                }else if($settings['account_act']=='emailact'){
                    $v_status = 'false';
                    $a_status = 'false';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    send_code($code,$email);
                    echo 'emailact';    
                    }
                }else if($settings['account_act']=='adminact'){
                    $v_status = 'false';
                    $a_status = 'false';
                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, a_status, reg_date, v_code, v_status) VALUES(:uname, :fn, :ln, :email, :pass, :gender, :a_status, :regd, :code, :v_status)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":uname"=>$username,":fn"=>$first_name,":ln"=>$last_name,":email"=>$email,":pass"=>$password,":gender"=>$gender,":a_status"=>$a_status,"regd"=>$reg_date,":code"=>$code,":v_status"=>$v_status));
                    echo 'adminact';
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "sorry".$e->getMessage();
            }
}
```

I think this will work fine for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer but php is accessing the information as my user is getting registered in my database plus i am also receiving the email of verification and if i change my setttings to not send email according to ajax success function i am also getting redirection and message with the two responses 'adminact' and 'noact'.

Comment: But thankfully i solved the issue thanks for the correct method of ajax.